# The Smith-Volterra-Cantor set

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be the SVC set.
Is S closed?
Does $\operatorname{Bd} S$ have measure zero?
I think the first answer is positive while the second is negative.
I need a rigorous proof.

Comment: What is the boundary of a closed set?

Answer (score 0):

The usual construction defines $S$ as a nested intersection of closed sets (in fact finite unions of closed intervals) so that $S$ is closed, and moreover $S$ has no interior points.

It follows that $S = \overline S = \mathrm{Bd\, }S \cup \mathrm{int\, S} =\mathrm{Bd\, }S$ so that $\mathrm{Bd\, }S$ has positive measure as long as $S$ does.

Comment: Why does $S$ have no interior points? I mean how can I visualize it?

Comment: Suppose that $s \in S$ is an interior point. Then there exists an interval $I$ with $x \in I \subset S$. Then $I \subset S_k$ for every set $S_k$ used in the interative construction of $S$, but the $S_k$ are defined as finite unions of intervals whose lengths are decreasing to zero, so at some point you would necessarily have $I \not\subset S_k$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...and to show that $\operatorname{Bd} S$ has positive measure does it suffice  to show that the sum of the removed intervals' lengths equals 1/2?

Comment: Sure. You just need to verify that $|S| > 0$.

Comment: One last thing, which is the usual construction of $S$ as a nested intersection of closed sets?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry includes a sketch of the construction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set